# How to create a dynamic config file sent via user-data property in Terraform module

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, cloud-init

I have a Nodejs server running Amazon Linux 2023 that is acting as an event subscriber.  I would like to configure some monitoring on it so that I can send logs to my monitoring service.  I was able to get the user-data section to run all the other commands successfully except the line that writes the config file.  Once this is working, I will need to expand it to install and configure Prometheus and node-exporter as well.

I'm not sure but I think I want it to run during the runcmd section so I can create the config file and then start the service based on the config file I just created.

If I remove the config file, everything else is successful.  I've tried using the write_file section but don't think that will work since I will need to enable and start the services once the configuration files are written.  I've tried every combination of quotes with echo, cat, and printf, I can think of.  Started with the cloud_config_config heredoc directly in the main.tf file and was trying to just pull in the filebeat_config. i.e.

```
main.tf file
...
  user_data                   = <<-EOF
    #cloud-config
    package_update: true
    package_upgrade: true
    selinux:
      mode: enforcing

    runcmd:
      ...
      - echo "${local.filebeat_config}" > /data_vol/configs/filebeats/filebeat.yml
EOF
```

Currently getting this error: (user_data value has been moved to locals.tf see below)

```
2023-08-17 00:19:11,336 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed loading yaml blob. Invalid format at line 52 column 2: "while scanning a block scalar
  in "<unicode string>", line 52, column 2:
     > /data_vol/configs/filebeats/fi ...
     ^
expected a comment or a line break, but found '/'
  in "<unicode string>", line 52, column 4:
     > /data_vol/configs/filebeats/file ...
       ^"
2023-08-17 00:19:11,654 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed loading yaml blob. Invalid format at line 52 column 2: "while scanning a block scalar
  in "<unicode string>", line 52, column 2:
     > /data_vol/configs/filebeats/fi ...
     ^
expected a comment or a line break, but found '/'
  in "<unicode string>", line 52, column 4:
     > /data_vol/configs/filebeats/file ...
       ^"
2023-08-17 00:19:11,667 - cloud_config.py[WARNING]: Failed at merging in cloud config part from part-001: empty cloud config
```

main.tf file

```
...
resource "aws_instance" "event_listener" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.amzLinux.id
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  key_name                    = data.aws_key_pair.existing_key.key_name
  subnet_id                   = data.aws_subnets.private.ids[1]
  user_data_replace_on_change = true
  user_data                   = local.cloud_config_config
  ...
}
...
```

locals.tf file

```
locals {
...
cloud_config_config = <<-EOF
  #cloud-config
    package_update: true
    package_upgrade: true
    selinux:
      mode: enforcing

    runcmd:
      - yum install -y https://s3.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com/amazon-ssm-${var.aws_region}/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
      - curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-8.9.0-x86_64.rpm
      - rpm -vi filebeat-8.9.0-x86_64.rpm
      - rm -f filebeat-8.9.0-x86_64.rpm
      - mkdir /data_vol -p
      - mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1
      - mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data_vol
      - echo "/dev/nvme1n1 /data_vol xfs defaults,nofail 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
      - mkdir -p /usr/share/ca-certificates/coralogix
      - curl -o /usr/share/ca-certificates/coralogix/ca.crt https://coralogix-public.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/certificate/ca.crt
      - dnf update -y && dnf install -y nano git nodejs
      - npm install -g pm2
      - mkdir -p /data_vol/configs/filebeats /data_vol/configs/prometheus /data_vol/configs/node-exporter /data_vol/logs/sf_event_listener

      - cat << ${local.filebeat_config} > /data_vol/configs/filebeats/filebeat.yml
EOF

  filebeat_config = <<-EOT
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  id: sf_event_listener_id
  paths:
  - "/data_vol/logs/sf_event_listener/err.log"
  fields_under_root: true
  fields:
    PRIVATE_KEY: "${var.coralogix_auth.private_key}"
    COMPANY_ID: ${var.coralogix_auth.company_id}
    APP_NAME: "salesforce"
    SUB_SYSTEM: "system_event"
  multiline.type: pattern
  multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: $${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["${var.coralogix_auth.hosts[0]}"]
  tls.certificate_authorities: ["/usr/share/ca-certificates/coralogix/ca.crt"]
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/usr/share/ca-certificates/coralogix/ca.crt"]
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~

EOT
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct problem here is that you are trying to construct a YAML document by concatenating strings together and it's inserting something that's making the resulting document invalid YAML syntax. You can avoid this class of problems by generating YAML using [`yamlencode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/yamlencode) instead, so that Terraform is the one responsible for producing valid YAML syntax and you only need to worry about making sure the data structure is correctly-shaped for cloud-init to decode.

```
locals {
  cloud_config_config = <<-EOT
    #cloud-config
    ${yamlencode({
      package_update = true
      package_upgrade = true
      selinux = {
        mode = "enforcing"
      }

      runcmd = [
        "yum install -y https://s3.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com/amazon-ssm-${var.aws_region}/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm",
        # (etc etc)
      ]
    })}
  EOT
}
```

Terraform will generate a valid YAML document containing the values you specify, using appropriate formatting/escaping to deal with problems such as there being newline characters in your `local.filebeat_config` value.

---

Although it's far outside the scope of what you were asking about, you might be interested to know that cloud-init has built-in support for [writing files to disk](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files), [partitioning and formatting disks](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html#disk-setup), [mounting partitions into the virtual filesystem](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html#adjust-mount-points-mounted), and [installing RPM packages](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html#install-arbitrary-packages), and so you might be able to replace this big sequence of imperative commands with a declarative configuration using cloud-init's other modules instead.

That sort of approach is often a better blend with Terraform's declarative style, though of course there's no harm in doing it imperatively via shell commands if you want to.

Comment: Thank you for the links and guidance.  I switched to using a template file for the filebeat_config section to try and git rid of the bad substitution error but either way it seems to still be there.  The problematic line is `path: $$${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml`.  If I use $$$$ I get the bad substitution error and if I use two it also errors out.  But $$$ gives me `path: 2404{path.config}/modules.d/*.yml`.  This is a static path to the filebeats module directory, would it be best to hard code it in, or is there a way around this?

Comment: NVM: adding `\$${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml` did the trick.  Thanks again!